# Create a pgfplots chart with two histograms in same plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart, histogram

Is it possible to create a plot with pgfplots with the histogram of two variables in the same chart, with a different color each?

This an example code I am using, but it creates a histogram where bars are not over each other. It has dummy data.

```latex
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar interval,
        xtick=,
        xticklabel={$\left [ \pgfmathprintnumber\tick, \pgfmathprintnumber\nexttick \right )$},
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis y line=left
    ]
        \addplot+ [hist={data=x, data max=10, data min=0}] table [row sep=\\, y index=0] {
data\\
1 \\
2 \\
3 \\
4 \\
3 \\
4 \\
5 \\
6 \\
4 \\
5 \\
6 \\
3 \\
5 \\
6 \\
7 \\
8 \\
6 \\
8 \\
8 \\
8 \\
3 \\
5 \\
8 \\
};
        \addplot+ [hist={data=x, data max=10, data min=0}] table [row sep=\\, y index=0] {
data\\
1 \\
2 \\
3 \\
7 \\
8 \\
3 \\
5 \\
6 \\
3 \\
8 \\
2 \\
1 \\
6 \\
3 \\
5 \\
8 \\
};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: the result]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  Please make your code compileable by providing some data. We do not have your `babyboom/weightgirl.dat` etc. Even the problem ist not caused by the data it makes it easier to understand the problem if the code is processable. You could for example make up some dummy data.

Comment: Thanks @Roland , done.

Comment: I am not 100% sure if I understand your question right, but maybe you have the same problem as stated in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/457776/95441. Could you comment on that?

Comment: My advice is that this is a bad plot because it's tough to follow. I would prefer dots connected by lines instead

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @stefan-pinnow , this [discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/457776/95441) helped in finding that the problem was the `interval` keyword. The solution then was defining the chart just as `ybar`:

```latex
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        % xtick=,
        % xticklabel={$\left [ \pgfmathprintnumber\tick, \pgfmathprintnumber\nexttick \right )$},
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis y line=left
    ]
        \addplot+ [opacity=0.5, hist={data=x, data max=10, data min=0}] table [row sep=\\, y index=0] {
data\\
1 \\
2 \\
3 \\
4 \\
3 \\
4 \\
5 \\
6 \\
4 \\
5 \\
6 \\
3 \\
5 \\
6 \\
7 \\
8 \\
6 \\
8 \\
8 \\
8 \\
3 \\
5 \\
8 \\
};
        \addplot+ [opacity=0.5, hist={data=x, data max=10, data min=0}] table [row sep=\\, y index=0] {
data\\
1 \\
2 \\
3 \\
7 \\
8 \\
3 \\
5 \\
6 \\
3 \\
8 \\
2 \\
1 \\
6 \\
3 \\
5 \\
8 \\
};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: The result]